# Valor inteiro em horas com Golang

Tags: golang

Estou tentando comparar 2 datas que possuem apenas 1 minuto de diferença entre elas e aplicar uma regra de preço baseado nesse tempo onde;

cada minuto deve ter o valor de R$0.10

```
st := time.Date(2019, 9, 21, 10, 10, 10, 0, time.UTC)
en := time.Date(2019, 9, 21, 10, 11, 10, 0, time.UTC)
diff := en.Sub(st) // 1m0s
```

Ao comparar as datas que possuem 0 horas de diferença o valor obtido é:

```
hours := (diff.Hours() * 60) * 0.10
// diff.Hours() é 0.016666666666666666 e não 0

minutes := diff.Minutes() * 0.10
```

**Esperado:** 0.10

**Obtido:** 0.20

Como o comentário sugere, a hora não é zero absoluto e por isso o calculo não estará correto, caso e converta para zero com `int()` o código não ira compilar pois estarei tentando fazer uma operação entre `int` e `float64`.

Como posso pegar o valor inteiro da diferença entre as horas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como em outras linguagens, usando o [`math.Round`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Round):

> Round returns the nearest integer, rounding half away from zero.

Dessa forma, vai truncar para o valor inteiro mais próximo, no seu caso `0.016666666666666666` vai ser `0`.

Após importar o `math`, só fazer:

```
round := math.Round(diff.Hours())
```

---

Segue um exemplo rodando no [*Go Playground*](https://play.golang.org/p/v6Xez5-2fYi)